# I can't import or use AdView for android

Tags: java, android, libgdx, admob

I'm making an android game using libgdx and I want to add ad banners so I followed some instructions online.

```
// I added this code on build.gradle in the dependencies:
compile "com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:8.3.0"
```

then set the minimum sdk to 9, It didn't ask me to sync so I did it manually(btw I'm using intellij) then when I tried to add codes on AndroidLauncher I was not able to use AdView(I can't even import it cause it doesn't appear).

**UPDATE**
my project structure is different
[image: my project structure doesn't have ads]

```
project(":android") {
    apply plugin: "android"

    configurations { natives }

    dependencies {
        compile project(":core")
        compile "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-backend-android:$gdxVersion"
        natives "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-platform:$gdxVersion:natives-armeabi"
        natives "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-platform:$gdxVersion:natives-armeabi-v7a"
        natives "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-platform:$gdxVersion:natives-x86"
        compile "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-box2d:$gdxVersion"
        natives "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-box2d-platform:$gdxVersion:natives-armeabi"
        natives "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-box2d-platform:$gdxVersion:natives-armeabi-v7a"
        natives "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-box2d-platform:$gdxVersion:natives-x86"
        compile "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-freetype:$gdxVersion"
        natives "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-freetype-platform:$gdxVersion:natives-armeabi"
        natives "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-freetype-platform:$gdxVersion:natives-armeabi-v7a"
        natives "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-freetype-platform:$gdxVersion:natives-x86"
        compile "com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:8.4.0"
    }
}
```

when I highlight the code for compiling the google play services - ads at the bottom it shows this message "Dependency on Play Services, but the SDK installation does not have the "Extras > Google Repository" installed. Open the SDK manager and install it." But I have the google repository installed and it's the latest version.

Comment: show the full block of your dependencies

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resolved the problem by updating my intellij ide from version 14 to 15, it basically reinstalled the ide and I had to import the entire project again.

Answer (score 3):

See if this helps: In `Android Studio` do the following-

1. Go to *File* --> *Project Structure*
2. On the left hand of the opened window, under *Developer Services*, select *Ads*
3. Check the checkbox next to *AdMod*. Your window should look like this:
   [image]
4. Click *OK*

This will add the required dependency to the Android's `build.gradle`, and sync Gradle.

When the sync is done, and just to make sure, clean and rebuild your project:

1. *Build* --> *Clean Project*
2. *Build* --> *Rebuild Project*

**Update:**
In effect, I think what this does is add the "Ad dependency" to the `build.gradle` file in the `android` project. So if the above tutorial does not work, try adding

```
dependencies {
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:8.4.0'
}
```

to the bottom of `build.gradle` file in the `android` project (*not* the one under `core` project).

I hope this helps.

Comment: @StormAsdg does my updated answer solve your problem?

Comment: So I added the code above on build.gradle under android but it's still the same problem.

Comment: @StormAsdg Did you clean and rebuild the project? If that doesn't help, try restarting your IDE as well.

Comment: I did all of that, the only thing I can import is "com.google.android.gms.ads.R;"

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

1. Remove the dependency and admob code
2. Do File -> Invalidate cache and restart
3. Add back the dependency.
4. Sync with gradle

Also make sure the components are downloaded and updated to the version you are using from Android SDK manager.

Comment: I did this but nothing happened, how do you sync with gradle? what I did is remove the all the dependency code including admob code on android